# Auto-incrementing IDs for Class Instances

Tags: python, uniqueidentifier, class-instance-variables

**Disclaimer**: This is for a semester project that I am currently working on. My question is regarding an implementation level detail and is not part of the grading scheme. I am only writing this code as a way to test the theory that I am proposing for the paper that I will write.

Also, I have considered the answers for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989870/assigning-ids-to-instances-of-a-class-pythonic) with little luck, so please do not consider this as a duplicate of that question

**The Problem**:

I have a graph (G=(V,E)). At some point in my algorithm, I need to turn this into a hypergraph (in a sense) by "collapsing" multiple nodes (say, `v_1, v_2, ..., v_n`) into one node (say, `v`). In the context of the problem, this implies that I need to change the edges in `E` such that any edge `e` between any of `v_1, v_2, v_n` and any other node `u` in `V` will be changed such that `e` is now between `u` and `v`.

In order to capture that there may now exist multiple distinct edges between any pair of nodes, I need to make a unique identifier for each edge. I have tried to do this by means of and ID, which I am currently unable to properly implement.

**This is what I've tried**:

```
class Edge:
    _ID = 0
    def __init__(self, u, v, w, c,f=0):
        self.id = Edge._ID 
        Edge._ID += 1
        self.src = u
        self.dest = v
        self.weight = w
        self.capacity = c
        self.flow = f
```

However, when I try to instantiate a new edge, I get the following error:

```
>>> e = Edge(1,3,5,10,0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "UnsplittableFlow.py", line 14, in __init__
    self.id = Edge._ID; Edge._ID += 1
UnboundLocalError: local variable '_ID' referenced before assignment
```

**EDIT**:

With the suggestions of some answers, I have been able to fix the instantiation-time error. However, another error persists. Here is my code and the errors:

```
class Edge:
    _ID = 0
    def __init__(self, u, v, w, c,f=0):
        self.id = self._ID; self._ID += 1
        self.src = u
        self.dest = v
        self.weight = w
        self.capacity = c
        self.flow = f
```

Error:

```
>>> e = Edge(1,3,5,10,0)
>>> e.id
0
>>> Edge._ID
0

>>> f = Edge(2,3,5,10,0)
>>> f.id
0
>>> Edge._ID
0
```

I'd appreciate any help

Thank you

Comment: Weird, it works for me. What version of Python are you using? (I tried both 2.7 and 3.1, but just in case...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still use `self` to get at the `_ID`.

```
self.id = self._ID 
self.__class__._ID += 1
```

If you're using CPython, you can have a lazy man's ID:

```
class Edge(object):
    @property
    def id(self): return id(self)
```

Comment: Which version of Python is this working on? It didn't work for me and I'm on `2.6.5`

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: You need to subclass `object` in Python2.x for descriptors to work ಠ_ಠ

Comment: Thank you, but I'm using your first solution, just because I'm more familiar with it. But thanks for letting me know - I will be trying your second solution when I have some time to kill

Answer (score 5):

Your edited code is treating `_ID` as though it were a instance variable, not a class variable. Based on Matt Joiner's answer what I think you mean is this:

```
class Edge:
    _ID = 0
    def __init__(self, u, v, w, c,f=0):
        self.id = self._ID; self.__class__._ID += 1
        self.src = u
        self.dest = v
        self.weight = w
        self.capacity = c
        self.flow = f
```

When I run your examples with this definition of `Edge`, I get:

```
>>> e = Edge(1,3,5,10,0)
>>> e.id
0
>>> Edge._ID
1
>>> f = Edge(2,3,5,10,0)
>>> f.id
1
>>> Edge._ID
2
```

Which is the desired result. However, others have pointed out that your original code worked for them, just like this code works for me, so I suspect the real problem is somewhere else in your code.

Comment: I think the problem with my original test had more to do with concurrency issues between changes that I was making to my code and the interpreter importing these changes. Somehow, restarting the interpreter fixed some things.

Thank you for demonstrating how Matt Joiner's code works (+1). But since he /did/ have the right answer first, I'm going to accept his.

Thank you again, for your help

Answer (score 2):

Before instantiating any Edge, you could set the class variable explicitly to 0 like so:

```
Edge._ID = 0
e = Edge(1,3,5,10,0)
f = Edge(2,3,4,5,0)
```

And the id's will be properly set.

Answer (score 2):

While the other answers offered are answer the asked question (which is why I am not unaccepting the one I originally accepted), the correct way to do this would be to use `itertools.count` as follows:

```
class Edge:
    _ID = itertools.count()
def __init__(self, u, v, w, c,f=0):
    self.id = self._ID.next()
```

Comment: @srgerg is right you are accessing self._ID which is an instance variable, You need to access the class _ID. Your first approach was correct  `self.id = Edge._ID; Edge._ID += 1`